# Pass information from 'inline' colorbox to parent page

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

This is more of a theoretical question about scope than anything too specific to my code but I'll give an example of what I'm trying to do anyway.

When a user selects something from a dropdown menu, colorbox overlays the screen and presents a hidden `<div>` on the opening page. No iframe is being used or no external html page being loaded. The `<div>` presented lives on the same page but is populated on the fly with a selection of images.

Colorbox presents the selection of images wrapped in `<div>`s. I want the user to be able to select an image and, depending on what they select, populate a form on the page underneath.

How can I get variables from the colorbox inline presentation to a function on the opening page?

I've tried a few things and looked at a few similar examples and nothing seems to work. The examples I've seen are from iframe loads not inline.

```
    function presentDifferentPrintings(cardPresentInfo) {

        // prevent submission until we're done here
        allowSubmitField = document.querySelector('#allowSubmit');
        allowSubmitField.value = 'false'; 

        // clear current hidden overlay div
        $( "div" ).remove( ".singleCardInOverlay" );

        // iterate through each printing, get set names, multiverseIDs and release dates to present
        var printingsNum = cardPresentInfo.printings.split("{|}");
        printingsNum.reverse(); // we want to see the latest cards first

        $.each(printingsNum, function(index, setCode) { 

            var setName = setNameCardIsFromField(setCode);
            var thisMultiverseID = getMVIDfromSetCode(cardPresentInfo['name'], setCode);
            var thisID = getIDfromSetCode(cardPresentInfo['name'], setCode);

            // create HTML for each card presentation
            var presentSingleCardHTML = "<div class='singleCardInOverlay' id='ovDiv"+thisID+"' onClick(fillInDetailsFromOverlay('"+thisID+"');) >";
            presentSingleCardHTML += '<img id="overlayImage" src="<?=$localCardImagePresentFolder?>'+thisMultiverseID+'.jpg" />';
            presentSingleCardHTML += '<p class="singleCardTextInOverlay">'+thisMultiverseID+' - '+setName+'</p>';
            presentSingleCardHTML += '</div>';



            // attach new div to hidden div if we have multiverseid
            if (thisMultiverseID != '') {
                $(presentSingleCardHTML).appendTo("#hiddenOverlayDiv");
            }                   
        });         

        $.colorbox({ inline:true, href:"#hiddenOverlayDiv", width:'80%', height:'80%', transition: "fade", opacity:0.85, returnFocus: true, trapFocus: true });

    }
```

And here's a very simplified version of the function I'm trying to call that lives on the page that summoned the colorbox:

```
    function fillInDetailsFromOverlay(thisID) {

        alert('success');
    }
```

Any ideas?

[image: Confused]

Answer (score 0):

Solution! After taking a nice break and playing cards with my kid ........

The way I got this working was to call my colorbox with a function assigned to the onComplete event hook that is built in. Instead of using the javascript onClick thingo in the div tag, I'm now listening for a click on any of the images with the 'singleCardInOverlay' class and passing the id for that div (which corresponds to the image selected) to the function.

Amazing what taking a break can do for your coding. I hope this helps someone.

```
        $.colorbox({ 
                   inline:true, 
                   href:"#hiddenOverlayDiv", 
                   width:'80%', 
                   height:'80%', 
                   transition: "fade", 
                   opacity:0.85, 
                   returnFocus: true,
                   onComplete: function() { 

                            $(".singleCardInOverlay").click(function(){ 
                                fillInDetailsFromOverlay(this.id);
                            });

                        },

                   trapFocus: true
                   });
```